# replace date in data.table in R returns unexpected value

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have one date variable that I formatted in the following way:

```
date  <- as.POSIXct(date, "%m-%d-%Y-%X")
```

For example, this can be the most recent date:

"2014-03-04 23:59:59 EST"

Now I have a data.table DT, in which a column time indicates some other date and is also formated as.POSIXct(format: "%m-%d-%Y-%X"). Now I want to replace some missing values (NA) in DT[,time] with my date variable "date":

```
library(data.table)    
DT <- DT[is.na(time), time:= date]
```

However, the dates that were replaced in the data.table are now "1970-01-01 14:30:24" (and not "2014-03-04 23:59:59").

What am I missing?

R: 3.02
Data.table: 1.9.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not data.table but essentially  because you try to mix "Datetime" types with an another type in the same vector. This reproduce the error:

```
  library(lubridate)  ## I am using lubridate for smart date conversion 
  origin <- mdy_hms("01-01-1970-00:00:01") ## Using origin as default value for dates
  date <- mdy_hms("3-11-2014-09:12:30")
  time = c(NA,1)
  ifelse(is.na(time),date,origin)
  [1] 1394529150          1       ## date is converted to numeric
```

one solution is to convert first to string and then convert again to a datetime

```
  ymd_hms(ifelse(is.na(time),paste(date),paste(origin))) ## paste used as as.character
```

using data.table , you can get the same result :

```
  dt = data.table(time=time,date = date)
  dt[,time:=ymd_hms(ifelse(is.na(time),paste(date),
                   paste(origin)))]

                 time                date
1: 2014-03-11 09:12:30 2014-03-11 09:12:30
2: 1970-01-01 00:00:01 2014-03-11 09:12:30
```

**PS: better to not coerce  time variable here and do operations whenever you have a missing values.**

Comment: Thanks agstudy - this solved the problem (though it seems a bit time-consuming to convert between the different classes). I was surprised that data.table recognized a date (as opposed to your example where it becomes the wrong class), but then made it the wrong time/day.